# Getting java.sql.Date to load to database

Tags: mysql, database, date

This program is working perfectly if I take out all references to date. It loads to the DB. However something here is preventing it from loading date to the DB. I'm not getting any error messages - it just isn't loading anything if I leave the date in. I've tried quite a few things such as what you can see that has been commented out. Can anyone help me out there? It's an SQL database. I running Derby jdbc. Here's the jsp code. You can ignore what I've commented out. It's just to let you see what I've tried.

```
       <%    
            int tableNum = 0; 
            String firstName = null; 
            String lastName = null;
            String Address = null;
            int Phone = 0;
            java.sql.Date date = null;
            int People = 0;





            if (request.getParameter("table_num")!=null){
                tableNum = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("table_num"));
            }
            if (request.getParameter("first")!=null){
                firstName = request.getParameter("first");
            }
            if (request.getParameter("last")!=null){
                lastName = request.getParameter("last");
            }
            if (request.getParameter("address")!=null){
                Address = request.getParameter("address");
            }
            if (request.getParameter("phone")!=null){
                Phone = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("phone"));
            }
            if (request.getParameter("date")!=null){

               java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(request.getParameter("date"));
               java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

              /* try{
               DateFormat fmt = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);

                  } catch (ParseException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(OutputProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               return null;
               }*/

               /*private Date convertToDate(String input) {
               try {
               return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);
               } catch (ParseException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(OutputProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               return null;
               }
               }*/

               /*DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
               Date myDate = formatter.parse(date);
               java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
               db.insert_date(sqlDate);*/

              /* SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
               java.util.Date utilDate = format.parse();*/

            } 
            if (request.getParameter("people")!=null){
                People = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("people"));
            } 
            if(tableNum != 0 && firstName != null && lastName != null && Address != null && Phone != 0 && date != null && People != 0){ 
                String URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Reservations";  
                String USERNAME= "johnp";
                String PASSWORD= "pease";
                Connection myCon = null;
                Statement ste = null;



                try{
                    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); 
                    System.out.println("Connecting to DB...");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Reservations","johnp", "pease");
                    System.out.println("Connected successfuly");

                    System.out.println("Inserting records into table");      
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    String query = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_RESERVATIONS(TABLE_NUM,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,TELEPHONE,DATE,NUMBER_IN_PARTY)VALUES(" + tableNum + "," + "'" + firstName + "'" + "," + "'" + lastName + "'" + ","  + "'" + Address + "'" + "," + Phone + "," + date + "," + People +")";



                    st.executeUpdate (query);  
                    System.out.println("Records inserted");
                    //con.close(); 

                   }catch(SQLException se){
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
                    se.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e){
                //Handle errors for Class.forName
                     e.printStackTrace(); 

            }
            }            
         %>
```

Comment: First of all find what value coming in `request.getParameter("date")` by using SOP

Comment: H Ponnarasu - Thanks for that but I'm new to this. What is SOP?